# cakePHP formHelper postLink image

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to output an image with a hyperlink wrapped around it instead of just a text hyperlink using cakePHP's formHelper::postLink function.

Does anyone know how to do this? I tried multiple things but couldn't get it working.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $country['Country']['id']),
    array('confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete ').$country['Country']['name'].'?')
)?>
```

So instead of 'Delete' I want to display an image.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what works for me.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
  $this->Html->image('icn_trash.png', array('alt' => __('Effacer'))), //le image
  array('action' => 'delete', $artist['Artist']['id']), //le url
  array('escape' => false), //le escape
  __('Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir effacer artiste #%s?', $artist['Artist']['id']) //le confirm
); //le voila
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    $this->Html->image('delete.png',
       array("alt" => __('Delete'), "title" => __('Delete'))), 
    array('action' => 'delete', $items['Item']['id']), 
    array('escape' => false, 'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly I dont think you want to use `$this->Form->postLink`

I think this page is exactly what you're after: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1441/image

This uses `$this->Html->image` to create the image and then you can pass a URL through as one of the parameters to specify the surrounding anchor link.

Comment: well, I guess he wants to combine the security of "post forms" with an image instead of text for delete links etc :) so an Image and Link itself woudn't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap in image inside a link element, but you need to set the escape option to false, like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('your_image_here.jpg', array(
        'alt' => 'Alternative Text for your image',
        'title' => 'Optional tooltip text for your image'
    ),
    array(
        'controller' => 'YourController',
        'action' => 'someAction'
    ),
    array(
        'escape' => false // Add this to avoid Cake from printing the img HTML code instead of the actual image
    )
);
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array("alt" => "Brownies")),
    array(
        'controller' => 'recipes',
        'action' => 'view',
        'id' => 6,
        'comments' => false
    )
)
```

Comment: In answering, it helps to add a little explanation as to *why* your answer solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score -4):

function delete_image(){

```
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')) {

        $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        $this->User->updateAll(
                            array('User.image' => "''"),
                            array('User.id' => $this->User->id)
                            );

        $this->Session->setFlash('The image has been deleted.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile'));      
        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, this has nothing to do with displaying an image.